# Compile several .toc into document

Tags: table-of-contents

I am preparing a teaching dossier and would like to include the table-of-contents from all my lecture notes.

Can the .toc files from these documents be read and compiled into a seperate latex file?

Here's the text from one such .toc

```
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Sequences}{1}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {2}Series}{6}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.1}Power Series}{19}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.1.1}Which functions may be represented as power series?}{25}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.2}The Generalised Binomial Theorem}{28}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {3}Differential Equations}{30}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3.1}Differential Equations}{30}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.1.1}Application: Radioactive Decay}{31}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.1.2}Separable ODE's}{33}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3.2}First Order Linear ODEs}{35}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.2.1}Mixing Problems}{37}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3.3}The Logistic Equation}{39}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3.4}2nd Order Linear ODE's with constant coefficients}{41}
\contentsline {subsubsection}{Boundary Value Problems}{42}
\contentsline {subsubsection}{Initial Value Problems}{42}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {4}Calculus of Several Variables}{48}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.1}Functions of Two Real Variables}{48}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.2}Limits and Continuity}{51}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.3}Partial Derivatives}{53}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.3.1}Higher Order Partial Derivatives}{54}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.4}Linear Approximation and tangent Planes}{56}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.5}The Chain Rule}{59}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.6}The Gradient}{59}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.7}Directional Derivatives}{60}
\contentsfinish
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but it requires some caution.

toc_1.toc generated from this file:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

toc_2.toc is your example.

And this file is used to generate the overall ToC:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\let\contentsfinish\relax
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Lecture Notes Contents}
\contentsline {part}{Lecture Notes 1}{}
\input{toc_1.toc}
\contentsline {part}{Lecture Notes 2}{}
\input{toc_2.toc}
\end{document}
```

You have to load packages, which leave commands in the .toc file. E.g. `blindtext` in the example or what ever package wrote `\contentsfinish` in your .toc file. You may have to disable commands written to the ToC. I did this here for `\contentsfinish` with

```
\let\contentsfinish\relax
```

For command with parameters this can be done with

```
\renewcommand{<command name>}[<number of parameters>]{}
```

Additionally, if you want to write the title of the lecture note before its contents, you have to use `\contentsline` to get the correct formatting. Here

```
\contentsline {part}{Lecture Notes 1}{}
```

was used. Of course, instead of or additionally to this you can also type normal text.

Another issue is the `hyperref` package. You can not mix .toc files from documents compiled with and without `hyperref`, because it redefines `\contentsline` with additional parameters.

If your lecture notes are all compiled with `hyperref` you have to use

```
\contentsline {part}{Lecture Notes 1}{}{}
```

to add the title. And of course, links won't work.

The result:

[image]

Comment: `\contentsfinish` comes from  `titletoc` package.